# How should I change this code to be able to swipe left/right more freely?

Tags: java, android, swipe, ontouchlistener

The problem is that I have to swipe almost strictly horizontally for the swipe action to work. I want more freedom when swiping. I want the swipe to also work when I swipe diagonally. How should I change this code?

here is the code

```
 public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {  

Context context = null;

private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureListener());

public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
}



private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
    private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffY > 0) {
                        onSwipeBottom();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeTop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: check out my answer, it should work out for you

Comment: please also accept the answer by hitting the little check mark under the upvote it this answer works for you :) that way we both get some reputation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer I havent tried it yet. I will check it if it works.

Comment: I hope I could be a help

Answer (score 1):

**Change  this:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            ------> if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) { <------
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {.....
```

**to this:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
            ------> if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY) - 50) { <------
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                }
            } else {.....
```

This will **allow you to swipe at a little more than a diagonal** and still be regestured as a side to side swipe.

This will also make you have to swipe more directly upward or downward.

If you do **not** want to respond to upward swipes, you can just do this:

```
@Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        boolean result = false;
        try {
            float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                    if (diffX > 0) {
                        onSwipeRight();
                    } else {
                        onSwipeLeft();
                    }
                } 
        } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: Hi tried your answer. The swipe works but there is no improvement.